# Linux: rexec not working when redirecting output into nohup

Tags: linux, nohup

I am able to execute rexec command in my terminal. If a execute the same as `nohup sh rexec.sh` it's not working.

**Command I used**

`nohup sh rexec.sh`

Error I got in `nohup.out`

```
rexec: Error in read from remote host: Bad file descriptor
```

How can I fix this?. Is there any alternate solution for executing command in remote machines?

I can't use `ssh` to execute remote commands , it is a routine tasks. Ssh asks password and also i can't generate public key over 20 machines in my network.  So I choosed rexec.

Comment: It seems to me the file is corrupted. Anyway, this can help: http://linux.sys-con.com/node/1053821

Comment: You should use `ssh` and you can have the same public key on many machines.